# DB Error - Events Dashboard

Tags: civievent, error-page

I'm working on a new install.

The Events/Dashboard menu choice generates a screen with the following error:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: unknown error
Return to home page.

There's nothing in the DB log.

I tried the Settings/Cleanup Caches and Update Paths/ panel doing both Cleanup Caches and Reset Paths, but to no avail.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you mention the CiviCRM version and cms you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 5.0.2, Drupal 7x.

Comment: Can you enable debugging options under Administer->System Settings-> Debugging and Error Handling 
And then goto your CMS root -> sites/default/files/civicrm/configandlog and find the most recently modified file, open it, delete the content and save. 
Do the same for your php/server error log
Go back to the error page, then open those 2 log files back and post what's displayed there
Also if you enable backtracing it will show further details on the error screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a core [bug](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/68) and was fixed at 5.1.0. You can either apply the patch from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11996) or Upgrade CiviCRM to 5.2.2.

HTH

Pradeep